# Central America, rain season and electronics

Tags: electronic-items, costa-rica, nicaragua, panama

I am a traveling developer and I need functional wifi and a laptop for my work. I would love to travel to the central americas (niceragua, costa rica and panama) for about a month during june but this is during the rainy season. I've heard rumors that the rain season is dreadful for electronic equipment and this would include my mac.

Could anybody confirm the following:

Is the humidity so bad that I would not be able to use a macbook in open air? Will I need to be in an airconditioned building all the time if I wish to work? Will I need plastic bags around the laptop while traveling?

Any advice would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not having direct experience from Central America but rather central Asia, such as rainforests in Indonesia where the humidity also easily surpasses 90%, I can tell you that you do not need to worry.

I never had an issue and I hardly ever use air conditioning, be it with cameras, laptops or cellphones etc.

If you want to be extra sure take silica gel packs and a large ziplock bag with you.

Answer (score 2):

Having spent years upon years through monsoons in India.. Laptops will not get spoilt.

However, I have heard of cases where people who lived in beach facing apartments faced faster corrosion of their electronics, but these were older electronics like amplifiers / equalizers.

Given todays electronics manufacturing (boards coated with some resistant stuff), especially laptops, I doubt if this will be an issue.